# IE6 and <select> - blinking page

Tags: internet-explorer-6, html-select, blink

I have a rather big page (with lots of html, css and js(dojo framework)). This page contains html-select element and when I select any option the page blinks in IE6. In other browsers it works fine.

Any ideas how to avoid blinking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is far too general a question. At least, please, provide an example, with code, and describe a specific problem that you are having.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't give a direct link to this page, but the same issue is at http://catalog.onliner.by/mobile/ when you change select in the left top part of the page (under logo)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would ignore this. My personal philosophy with IE6 is: It needs to work, but I don't care how it looks.

Perhaps you don't have the luxury.